# wxTreeCtrl always shows selected item as focused, on GTK2 and GTK3

Tags: gtk, wxwidgets

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 with the Breeze theme selected for both GTK2 and GTK3. Running the 'treectrl' program from the 'examples' directory on the source distribution creates the window shown below:

[image]

The window has a wxTreeCtrl with some items and a text control showing a log. If I click on an item on the tree it's background turns blue, indicating both selection and focus on the wxTreeCtrl. If I them click on the text control the caret appears, indicating that the text control has taken the focus but the selected item on the tree remains with a blue background.

Other (pretty much all other) controls change the background colour of the selection to a different colour to indicate selection without focus.
Why doesn't wxTreeCtrl follow this and can it be reverted back to the normal behaviour?

------ Edit -------

I've build a native GTK3 app using the code :

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

enum {
  COLUMN = 0,
  NUM_COLS
};

GtkTreeModel *create_and_fill_model(void) {
    
  GtkTreeStore *treestore;
  GtkTreeIter toplevel, child;

  treestore = gtk_tree_store_new(NUM_COLS,
                  G_TYPE_STRING);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &toplevel, NULL);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &toplevel,
                     COLUMN, "Scripting languages",
                     -1);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &child, &toplevel);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &child,
                     COLUMN, "Python",
                     -1);
  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &child, &toplevel);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &child,
                     COLUMN, "Perl",
                     -1);
  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &child, &toplevel);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &child,
                     COLUMN, "PHP",
                     -1);

  return GTK_TREE_MODEL(treestore);
}


GtkWidget *create_view_and_model(void) {
    
  GtkTreeViewColumn *col;
  GtkCellRenderer *renderer;
  GtkWidget *view;
  GtkTreeModel *model;

  view = gtk_tree_view_new();

  col = gtk_tree_view_column_new();
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_title(col, "Programming languages");
  gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), col);

  renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
  gtk_tree_view_column_pack_start(col, renderer, TRUE);
  gtk_tree_view_column_add_attribute(col, renderer, 
      "text", COLUMN);

  model = create_and_fill_model();
  gtk_tree_view_set_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), model);
  g_object_unref(model); 

  return view;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *view;
  GtkTreeSelection *selection; 
  GtkWidget *vbox;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Tree view");
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 350, 300);

  vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 2);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

  view = create_view_and_model();
  selection = gtk_tree_view_get_selection(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view));

  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), view, TRUE, TRUE, 1);
  
  GtkWidget *entry = gtk_entry_new();
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), entry, TRUE, TRUE, 1);

  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
          G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

that shows a window with a Tree View control on top and a Entry control on bottom. The behaviour is the same, as seen in the picture:

[image]

Comment: does any other "native" GTK applications using tree control behave like this?

Comment: Code::Blocks uses wxWidgets and behaves the same way; the projects tab uses a wxTreeCtrl (at least it so seems) and clicking on an editor tab moves the focus to it but the item selected on the tree remains shown as focused.

Comment: C::B is not native GTK application. Try to run an actual `GTK` application from GNOME distribution. Also - what version of wxWidgets do you use?

Comment: wxTreeCtrl is an older generic control. It may not work well with your theme for one reason or another.  You can try using wxDataViewTreeCtrl instead.

Comment: I've built a native GTK3 test app with 'tree_view' and 'entry' widgets and the behaviour is the same. The wxWidgets library I'm building against is Git HEAD (currently 3.1.6)

Comment: @New Pagodi: The example app for the wxDataViewTreeCtrl included in the wxWidgets distribution behaves the same.

Comment: So I guess that's just how those controls look and behave.  I agree it's annoying, but I don't know what can be done to change it.